# Reasons why living fossils exist?

Tags: evolution, species

> A [living fossil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Living_fossil) is a living species (or clade) that
>   appears to be similar to another species otherwise known only from fossils,
>   typically with no close living relatives.

A living fossil is considered as a successful organism, which has made its way through many  major [extinction events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extinction_event). Also, the morphology of living fossils resemble some species of organisms which we know only through their fossil remains.

- What is the reason for a particular type of species to become a living fossil; is the engineering of this particular species extraordinary, in that it can survive any selection process encountered thus far?
- Is there not enough selection pressure exerted on this species in order to force it to change morphologically?
- Have these organisms modified themselves, so that currently their morphology seems to be similar to a fossil organism?

Comment: wasn't every fossil once a living fossil?

Comment: @aandreev: The term "living fossil" describes an organism which is alive today and it has great resemblance with some ancient creature(which is luckily fossilized). Every fossil we found are remains of living organisms and not remains of fossil :)

Comment: I don't think there is a reason to it. The other species in the clade just perished. If we kill all apes and monkeys (just keep one body in a museum) then we will become living fossils too.

Comment: "*Is there not enough selection pressure exerted on this species in order to force it to change morphologically*"…… This is not how evolution happens. They don't adopt a morphology because of selection pressure. The pressure selects certain traits which may include a particular morphology.

Comment: Of course the selection pressure changes the morphology. These are just two different ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: I think living fossil is a fairly meaningless term, since there will be fossils of extinct species out there resembling many living species.
Species which are the sole survivor of a clade were simply the most successful, I suppose. If you are wondering: why has a species remained the sole survivor of a clade for a long time without speciating again - perhaps the niche it occupies isn't very conducive to speciation, e.g. mass synchronised mating. Perhaps we just don't recognise the different species of e.g. horseshoe crab which exist, for what they are.

Comment: @WYSIWYG: However selection pressure can favor morphological changes by selecting particular traits. More selection pressure is exerted on a morphological trait makes it more susceptible to change. So lesser selection pressure could make the morphology immutable.

Comment: @Teige: " perhaps the niche it occupies isn't very conducive to speciation". Your words seems marvelous but HOW ?

Comment: There's a paleontologist from the University of Chicago called David Raup who wrote a book on extinction: "The disturbing reality is that for none of the thousands of well-documented extinctions in the geologic past do we have a solid explanation of why the extinction occurred... We have many proposals in specific cases, of course: ... These are all plausible scenarios, but no matter how plausible, they cannot be shown to be true beyond reasonable doubt. Equally plausible alternative scenarios can be invented with ease". so it seems we may have to admit our ignorance in this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One part of your question betrays a serious error:

> - Is there not enough selection pressure exerted on this species in order to force it to change morphologically?

Actually the reverse is true; constancy of form can only be maintained in the presence of continuous selective pressure. It's just that this is stabilising selection that acts to maintain the existing form rather than push the organism to new morphologies. In fact, *most* selection acts in this manner. This shouldn't surprise you: organisms are typically well adapted to their environments so changes are more likely to reduce fitness than increase fitness.

It's also worth noting that although living fossils show little morphological change they can continue to show change at the molecular level at rates as high as, or higher than, other organisms - e.g. ([May et al 2007](http://www.cell.com/trends/genetics/abstract/S0168-9525%2808%2900003-6); [Cao et al 2013](http://www.nature.com/ncomms/2013/131015/ncomms3602/full/ncomms3602.html)).

Comment: Good point about molecular vs. morphological evolution.

Comment: @Jack Aidley: Consider an organism which is well adapted to its environment, if a change happens it makes the organism shifted to a reduced fitness state(as you mentioned). Then if a morphological alteration could bypass the fitness reduction and make it more fit. How is this statement invalid by your perception ?

Comment: @Jay: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you're asking?

Answer (score 7):

**TL;DR:** Living fossils are the children of long-dead fossilised creatures that were good at being alike, other animals are the children that were good at being different.

The boring answer is that living fossils are around because nothing has happened to make them go extinct.

The more exciting answer is a tale of intrigue and lies stretching back hundreds of millions of years:

### The lie that is the 'species'

The notion of a species is, of course, a lie. It's a useful lie, and one without which the equally useful field of taxonomy would be impossible, but a lie all the same. Every living thing is ultimately a unique individual unto itself. We group these individuals up and call them things, according to things that are more or less arbitrary, and we arrange these groups into bigger groups and fill books upon books with this method, because it makes it super easy to get a good overview of how life developed.

However, if we want to understand the details, we have to see past species, and look at the lineages.

### The shark, our ancestor<sup>1</sup>

One such lineage that is of interest is that of the shark. Sharks are *[ancient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shark#Evolution)*: They are roughly as old as plants, and older than almost all land fauna. They are vicious, unrelenting killing machines, and all but perfectly suited for being this, with their sleek shape, their conveyor belts of teeth, and rough skin. At some point way back when, however, the lineage of sharks split in two: One branch that leads to fish, amphibians and eventually dinosaurs, squirrels and dolphins, and one that leads to sharks. The forebear to all these things were the [early cartilaginous fish of the Cambrian ocean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution_of_fish#Jawed_fish).

To answer the question as posed, we have to compare the success factors of the two lineages.

### Why sharks are still around as living fossils

The real answer here is that, in a very real sense, they aren't. Modern sharks are no more alike their long-dead forebears than squirrels are. However, the biological niche inhabited by sharks (apex predator) is a successful one, and sharks, already existing in this niche, have had successful children, made more successful by being superficially and behaviourally *alike* to their parents, and so, the modern shark presents as a living fossil.

### Why shark contemporaries are *not* still around as living fossils

The real answer here is that, in a very real sense, they are. Morphological differences aside, squirrels are no more different from their long-dead forebears than sharks. Rather, crowded niches have made generation upon generation of increasingly squirrely animals more successful by being superficially and behaviourally *different* from their parents, and so, modern squirrels have arisen.

---

**Edit:** Footnotes:

1. The shark is not in fact our ancestor, rather [Cambrian early jawed fish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution_of_fish#Jawed_fish) are. The image of a shark is however far more evocative and easier to talk about.

Comment: "The shark, our ancestor" can you provide some reference for your claim that fishes are evolved from sharks. Also there is no reference for any of your claims, so how can I accept your answer ?

Comment: @Jay Sure, let me get right on that.

Comment: @Jay And there I've specified more exactly our relationship with sharks.

Comment: " the lineage of sharks split in two: One branch that leads to fish, amphibians and eventually dinosaurs, squirrels and dolphins, and one that leads to sharks". Here do you meant the shark instead of "Cambrian early jawed fish".

Comment: @Jay The statement "The lineage of X split in two: One branch that leads to Y and one branch that leads to Z." is equally valid for _literally_ any known living things X, Y and Z, which is largely the point of the answer. The details of which creatures are descent from which _really_ aren't important to this answer. Besides all of which, whether we are descent from sharks is really a subjective matter: If you follow the lineage of sharks backwards, parent-to-parent-to-parent you'll find that it's _damn_ hard to place a hard line on where 'early jawed fish' end and 'sharks' begin.

Comment: So you must have mentioned these X,Y and Z and not sharks because the fellow readers will be misguided by this fact. Also finally, in the question I have pointed out three facts(in bullets), to which one do you agree as the reason behind this process or could your suggest a new one. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21804/discussion-between-williham-totland-and-jay).

Comment: While we are at that, the concept of multicellular organisms is a "useful lie" too, as they are actually just a complicated colony of unicellular organisms.